# Die APP Systemeinstellungen ist nicht auffindbar (The APP system settings can not be found)

Tags: settings, system

habe die App Systemeinstellungen (System Settings) deinstalliert. Wie bekomme ich diese wieder zurück oder neu.

Danke euch.

**Translation:**
I have uninstalled the app System Settings. How do I get these back or new.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal öffnen und folgendes eingeben:

```
apt search switchboard
```

und danach alles, was aufgelistet wird mit:

```
sudo apt install "Paketname"
```

installieren. Der Paketname ist jeweils fett und farbig.

**Translation:** Open the terminal and enter the following:

```
apt search switchboard
```

and then everything listed with:

```
sudo apt install "package name"
```

to install. The package name is bold and colored.

[image: Terminal-Screenshot]

Comment: Danke Frank. Ich bin begeistert. Alles OK.